# Connection dropped due to file size

Tags: posts, media, draft

We use Open Live Writer to upload to our Wordpress Blog on GoDaddy.  It takes us numerous times to upload the draft with pictures to the Blog as we get the error message of lost connection.  I have noticed in the Media file that the pictures are uploading in stages.  That is, after I get the connection error message I check the Media file and more pictures have uploaded.  Finally the Draft shows up in the Post file and all pictures are there.  Sometimes I need to change the hotpot I am using as it also seems to get stuck.

Other than a smaller Blog posting what can we due to limit these disconnections?

Comment: What is the hotpot?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think OP meant "hotspot".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to push too much data at one time. GoDaddy may be terminating the connection because of a size limit per request or the upload is taking longer than they allow (because it is so large.) In either case it is a sign the amount of data is too large.

A possible solution is breaking the upload into smaller pieces. Meaning: make some edits, push, make more edits, push. Instead of making many edits at one time and pushing them all at once.

You can also consider moving to a host that offers staging environments. In this situation you would be able to press a button and create a clone of you site (depending on the host this may or may not be accessible to the public). On this clone you would log into your WordPress dashboard, make edits the normal WordPress way, then press a button to push the changes to your live (public) website.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think it is a hosting problem. I think it is a browser-type timeout; too much data being sent by LiveWriter for it's browser-like HTTP connection.

There are some things you can do to extend the post_size (see here https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-maximum-upload-file-size/ for some hints on changing those values.

You might also consider optimizing your images before uploading to reduce the file size. Lots of pre-processing programs to shrink images.